# Using SED with RegEx to put underlines back in links in hundreds of CSS files

Tags: css, regex, linux, sed

I've got hundreds (more than 700) sets of web folders, each containing discrete CSS stylesheets. (If you are curious, they are online courses.)

Recently a decision was made that links should have underlines. I know that W3C decided that a long time ago, but this is a University and they like to re-decide things.

I've been trying to update all the CSS files using a RegEx search and replace.

Major hurdles so far have been:

- Windows. I don't like it, I'm not using it. Command-line utilities like FART are great for single-line stuff, but writing a more customized and powerful search proved to be too much for it.
- Multi-Line. CSS files are usually structured like this:

  ```
  a, .surveypopup{
  text-decoration:none;
      cursor:pointer;
  }
  ```

  Which means that the selector (the part before the "{") is always on a separate line from the goodies. I want to match all selectors that modify "a" without an event (like :hover) and ensure that anything with "text-decoration:none" becomes "text-decoration:underline" without messing up any other styling code that may be sandwiched between.
- Case-insensitive. For RegEx, this shouldn't be a problem. The authors of this CSS may or may not have gotten creative with their capitalization.

The command-line I'm currently erroring with is this:

```
find . -iname "*.css" | xargs sed -i "" "s|\(\ba\(,\|\.\|\s\|\b\)\[^\{\]\*\{\[^\}\]\*\)text-decoration\:none|a.\1text-decoration:underline;|g"
```

Which produces:

```
sed: 1: "s|\(\ba\(,\|\.\|\s\|\b\ ...": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)
```

I'm wondering if my needs justify writing a bash script? It would be nice to create a backup of each file if a modification is required. Multiple operations like that would be easier in a script...

Either way, I assume I'm having problems because I don't know what to escape for sed, and what not to escape.

Please help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just add a new style which overrides the old ones? e.g. `a { text-decoration: underline !important }`

Comment: Yes, it would be easier. The anal-retentive part of me looks at the bottom of these files (which have been around for 5+ years now) and cringes at the 40 or more styles which my predecessors have added that way. Everything can't be !important. Yes it would work, but it's sloppier than I'd like to be.

Comment: Isn't replacing `a, .surveypopup{ text-decoration:none; }` problematic if `.surveypopup` still **isn't** supposed to be underlined? Anyway, I wouldn't try to do this in `sed`; multiline in perl or even python will be easier.

Comment: I assume that people would have created style selector groups for similar things. You're right, maybe they didn't. The logical thing would be to use CSS selector groups to style things that should look the same. In this case the surveypopup should look the same as a link, but in concept you're still right - it is an assumption and is bound to be wrong in some case somewhere. However, in that case I doubt that an underline will be a problem. It will be confusing, potentially, but it was set to share an underline with links and as such it __should__ work effectively.

Comment: I'll look into using perl for this, or simply hop on the bandwagon and !important it. I've wasted too much time on this already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operating on an entire file at once you can use:

```
s/(\ba(?=(?:\.|,|\s|{|#)))([^}{]*?{[^}]*?text-decoration:\s*)none(\s?!important)?;/$1$2underline;/g
```

More nicely formatted, this is:

```
s/                          # find and replace
    (                       # group 1
        \b                  # a word boundary
        a                   # followed by 'a'
        (?=                 # where the next character (positive lookahead)
            (?:             # (inside a non-capturing group)
              \.|,|\s|{|#   # is one of '.', ',', '{', '#' or whitespace
            ) 
        )
    )
    (                       # group 2
        [^}{]*?             # then non-greedily match anything up to a '{' or '}'
                            # if '}' is found, the next character will not match
                            # and therefore the whole regex will not match
        {                   # and find the '{'
        [^}]*?              # and then non-greedily match anything until we 
                            # find 'text-decoration', but don't keep matching
                            # when a '}' is found
        text-decoration:    # then find 'text-decoration'
        \s*                 # and optional whitespace
    )
    none                    # and 'none'
    (\s?!important)?        # and optional '!important'
    ;                       # and a ';'
/
    $1                      # replace by group 1
    $2                      # then group 2
    underline;              # then 'underline;'
/g
```

Example file:

```
$ cat test.css
a { text-decoration: none; }
b, a { text-decoration: none; }
b, a, u { text-decoration: none; }
b, a.cat, u { text-decoration: none; }
b, a.cat, u { text-decoration: none !important; }
b, a, u {
    text-decoration: none;
}
b, a, u {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
b, a, u {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

And result:

```
perl -0777 -p -e 's/(\ba(?=(?:\.|,|\s|{|#)))([^}{]*?{[^}]*?text-decoration:\s*)none(\s?!important)?;/$1$2underline;/g' test.css
a { text-decoration: underline; }
b, a { text-decoration: underline; }
b, a, u { text-decoration: underline; }
b, a.cat, u { text-decoration: underline; }
b, a.cat, u { text-decoration: underline; }
b, a, u {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
b, a, u {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
b, a, u {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

You can use perl's `-i` flag (don't forget to set a backup extension!) to operate on the files in-place.

There's obviously a lot of other possible CSS rules which can include an `a`; e.g. `html>a` or `div a b`; this regex will not find the first, and will find the second, but will be "wrong" in both cases. Basically, you can use regex for these types of tasks only when you can make strong assumptions about the text you're manipulating.

**update** added `}` to part of a rule to avoid matching, e.g.:

```
b { background-image: url('http://domain.com/this is a picture.jpg'); }
u { text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using RegEx to parse CSS. Use a CSS parser instead, you'll save yourself a world of trouble.